# Cascading selects with JsViews: Making a select observe another select

Tags: jsrender, jsviews

I have two select elements on my page, "Make" and "Model". I have a large array containing all Models, each with a makeId, which correspond to the values of the items in the Make select. I'm using a converter to populate the data of the Model select based on the selected Make. The converter works on the initial load of the page, but it doesn't seem to be changing when I change the Make. It also changes if the Models array is modified in any way. Is there a way to get the Model select observe the Make select? I tried passing a variable to the second select containing the value of the first, but that didn't cause it to observe the change. Here is what the two selects look like:

```
<select id="Makes" data-link="selectedMake">
  {^{for ~root.data.Makes}}
    <option value="{{:value}}">{{:text}}</option>
  {{/for}}
</select>

<select id="Models" data-link="selectedModel">
  {^{for ~root.data.Models convert='getModelsForMake' ~make=selectedMake }}
    <option value="{{:value}}">{{:text}}</option>
  {{/for}}
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, that can be done. I'll post some suggestions in the next couple of days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that when the `selectedMake` changes, it triggers a refresh of the `{^{for ~root.data.Models convert='getModelsForMake'}}`. The problem is that your converter, `getModelsForMake` converter depends on `selectedMake` - but the {^{for}} tag doesn't 'know that'.

There are a few different ways you can indicate a dependency on `selectedMake`.

Declare dependency on the `{^{for}}`:

```
{^{for ~root.data.Models convert='getModelsForMake' depends='selectedMake'}}
```

Declare dependency on the converter, by adding code:

```
$.views.converters.getModelsForMake.depends = "~root.selectedMake";
```

Pass in selectedMake as second argument on `{^{for}}`:

```
{^{for ~root.data.Models selectedMake convert='getModelsForMake'}}
```

Introduce dependency by including a 'null check' for selectedMake, on `{^{for}}`:

```
{^{for selectedMake && ~root.data.Models convert='getModelsForMake'}}
```

Incidentally, I have alternative versions of cascading selects now included in the docs in the [Data-linked <select> elements](https://www.jsviews.com/#link-select@cascade). (That link takes you to the relevant section).

Comment: I added the selectedMake as the second argument in the `{^{for}}`, and that did the trick. I'm looking forward to seeing what you're working on for alternatives, as the application I'm working on has a fair amount of these cascading selects.

Comment: I updated above with a link that takes you to the new doc topic section.